# what is the right query for this question?

Tags: sql, sql-server, adventureworks

How to Identify the 3 most important (highest revenue) cities and show a break down of 3 top level categories against these cities.

I work on adventureworkslt2014.

this is my query, but I got the best three sales from the same city:

```
select top 3 sum(TotalDue) as bestrevenue,city,pc.Name 
from SalesLT.ProductCategory as pc
join SalesLT.Product p 
on pc.ProductCategoryID =p.ProductCategoryID
join SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail as sod
on sod.ProductID=p.ProductID 
join SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader as soh 
on soh.SalesOrderID = soh.SalesOrderID
join SalesLT.[Address] addr
on addr.AddressID = soh.BillToAddressID
group by city,pc.Name
order by bestrevenue desc`
```

the expected result I should get 9 rows, every three rows have same city with it's highest sales also from which categories came this highest sale.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select t.*
from(select city, pc.Name, sum(TotalDue) as bestrevenue,
            row_number() OVER(partition by city,Name ORDER BY sum(TotalDue) desc) as RN 
     from SalesLT.ProductCategory as pc join 
          SalesLT.Product p 
          on pc.ProductCategoryID =p.ProductCategoryID join 
          SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail as sod
          on sod.ProductID=p.ProductID join 
          SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader as soh 
          on soh.SalesOrderID = soh.SalesOrderID join 
          SalesLT.[Address] addr
          on addr.AddressID = soh.BillToAddressID
     group by city,pc.Name
    ) t
where RN <= 3;
```

Comment: i have tried it , i got more than 754 rows... and resultset was completely wrong, i need just the three best sales for each city and thier categoires ..

Comment: i think the filtering with 'where RN <= 3' like that , does not work with sql server